# Proof that $|3^b(c+1)-2^d(a+1)|<\frac{3^b}{2^{2n-1}}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am working through some of my notes from my university days (about 20 years ago) and have stumbled upon a theorem.

For any positive integer $n$ and for any interval of the form $[\frac{a}{3^b},\frac{a+3}{3^b}]$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers and $a$ is divisible by $3$, there is an interval of the form $[\frac{c}{2^d},\frac{c+2}{2^d}]$ contained in the first interval where $c$ and $d$ are positive integers and $c$ is divisible by $2$ such that $|3^b(c+1)-2^d(a+1)|<\frac{3^b}{2^{2n-1}}$.

I have no idea why this is true. I am trying to find a proof for it and am completely stuck. Does anyone have a good proof for this theorem?

Comment: Just curious: why did you tag your question as "prime-numbers"?

Comment: @uniquesolution There seems to be some interplay between the primes $2$ and $3$ and possibly some connection to diaphantine equations and their solutions when coefficients are coprime. Maybe I shouldn't have tagged it as such. I'm new here so feel free to correct my tagging :)